# Obtaining classes of generic types of an ancestor class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Is there an easy way to obtain the generic parameters of an ancestor class ? (not the immediate parent class, as discussed here: http://blog.xebia.com/2009/02/07/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/ , but any ancestor class in the hierarchy.

For example: Let's say we have these classes:

```
class Class1<O,P,Q> {}

class Class2<R,S> extends Class1<R, String, S> {}

class Class3<U> extends Class2<List,U> {}

class Class4<W> extends Class2<W,Set> {}
```

How could I know, given a particular descendant class (for example `Class3` or `Class4`) the type of the parameters of the ancestor class `Class1` ? Note that all this information is present at compile time!.

For example, I know that for `Class3<U>`, `Class1` will be instantiated with: `<List, String, U>`.

In the same way, for `Class4<W>`, `Class1` will be instantiated with `<W, String, Set>`. So it should be possible to do this with reflection. Note that I am not interested in the runtime values of the parameters, but just about compile time data.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Good question... I didn't know you could get parameterised-types out of relections at all... I thought something called "type erasure" got in the way... where all reference to the actual types where removed during compilation. I'll be interested in the answer to this one, if there is one. Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Hi @corlettk, as far as I know type erasure deletes runtime type information, not compile time information about the types. Note that even this statement is not 100% true since there are certain tricks you could do to obtain the runtime time information as discussed in the link I posted above.

Comment: I've just read through the linked "tutorial". Interesting. I guess you could take that code and extend to look for the parameterizedType of O, P, and Q in inheritance heirarchy... presuming that .getGenericSuperclass() can be called on the RESULT of a call to .getGenericSuperclass()... I'll go play (which might take a while) and then post some sort of answer. Cheers.

Comment: As you demonstrate in your last paragraph, you can easily find out yourself by just following the trail up the hierarchy. Why do you need to do this in code (since it's not at runtime)?

Comment: @ChadSchouggins, what I want to say is that the information I need is available at compile time. But the name of the particular descendant class is known at runtime only.

Comment: Hi @corlettk, yes I think it can be programmed, but I think it is a bit annoying there is not already in Java an API for asking easily this kind of questions. I think the Java reflection protocol and type system is so messy, patched and incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Here's an approach... I'm not saying this is the best (or even a good) approach, I'm just saying you might be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
package forums;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Class1<O,P,Q> {}

class Class2<R,S> extends Class1<R, String, S> {}

class Class3<U> extends Class2<List,U> {}

class Class4<W> extends Class2<W,Set> {}

public class GenericTypeHeirarchy
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      PrintGenericAncestorTypes(Class4.class, "    ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static void PrintGenericAncestorTypes(Class clazz, String pad) {
    Type supaType = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType paramSupaType = null;
    if (supaType instanceof ParameterizedType)
      paramSupaType = (ParameterizedType) supaType;
    if (paramSupaType == null)
      return; // INVALID REQUEST! Parent isn't a generic type.
    Type[] supasArgTypes = paramSupaType.getActualTypeArguments();  //actually returns TypeVariableImpl[]
    for ( Type t : supasArgTypes ) {
      // Type subinterfaces: GenericArrayType, ParameterizedType, TypeVariable<D>, WildcardType
      if (t instanceof TypeVariable) {
        System.out.println( pad + clazz.getName() + ": <" + t + ">");
        PrintGenericAncestorTypes(clazz.getSuperclass(), pad + "    "); // <<<< RECURSION >>>>
      } else {
        System.out.println( pad + clazz.getName() + ": " + t);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

This probably still isn't what you're after... which I think would be the Class (or the class name) for each generic-arguement-type... but it's as far as I can get. I don't know how to get a Class for a Type... the Type interface is empty, so it'd have to be cast to something to get a class (or class-name) from... and read-arg-types (like java.lang.String) wheren't any of the known-subinterfaces-of-Type (GenericArrayType, ParameterizedType, TypeVariable, or WildcardType). I presumed that a `TypeVariable<D>` is an `instanceOf TypeVariable`.

So here's my improved version, but I'm stumped on where to go from here.

```
package forums;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Class1<O,P,Q> {}

class Class2<R,S> extends Class1<R, String, S> {}

class Class3<U> extends Class2<List,U> {}

class Class4<W> extends Class2<W,Set> {}

public class GenericTypeHeirarchy
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      PrintGenericTypeTree(Class4.class);
      System.out.println("--------------------------\n");
      PrintGenericTypeTree(Class3.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static void PrintGenericTypeTree(Class clazz) {
    if (clazz == null || clazz == java.lang.Object.class)
      return;
    //
    // class Class4<W> extends
    //
    System.out.print( "class " + clazz.getName() );
    TypeVariable[] argTypes = clazz.getTypeParameters();
    if (argTypes.length == 0)
      return;
    System.out.print( "<" );
    boolean first = true;
    for ( TypeVariable t : argTypes ) {
      System.out.print( (first?"":", ") + t.getName() );
      first = false;
    }
    System.out.print("> extends ");
    //
    // Class2<W,Set>
    //
    Class supaClass = clazz.getSuperclass();
    System.out.print(supaClass.getName());
    Type genericSupaType = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType paramSupaType = null;
    if (genericSupaType instanceof ParameterizedType)
      paramSupaType = (ParameterizedType) genericSupaType;
    if (paramSupaType == null) { // Parent isn't a generic type.
      System.out.println();
      return; 
    }
    Type[] supasArgTypes = paramSupaType.getActualTypeArguments();  //actually returns TypeVariableImpl[]
    first = true;
    System.out.print( "<" );
    for ( Type t : supasArgTypes ) {
      System.out.print( (first?"":", ") + t );
      first = false;
    }
    System.out.println(">");
    PrintGenericTypeTree(supaClass);
  }

}
```

... and here's the output ...

```
C:\Java\home\src\forums>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\java.exe" -Xms4m -Xmx256m -enableassertions -cp c:\java\home\src;C:\Java\home\classes; forums.GenericTypeHeirarchy

class forums.Class4<W> extends forums.Class2<W, interface java.util.Set>
class forums.Class2<R, S> extends forums.Class1<R, class java.lang.String, S>
class forums.Class1<O, P, Q> extends java.lang.Object
--------------------------

class forums.Class3<U> extends forums.Class2<interface java.util.List, U>
class forums.Class2<R, S> extends forums.Class1<R, class java.lang.String, S>
class forums.Class1<O, P, Q> extends java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Ian Robertson came up with a fair [solution](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860). As I recall it is not complete, but it should easily get you started.

Comment: Yeah that starts from where the OP's code gives out... I should read the COMPLETE article before I comment on it. Sigh.